# Difference between 'feel' and 'feel like' in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs

Let's say I am talking to my friend, and he says

> I **feel like** taking a week off at work.

and I want to say

> Why do you **feel like that/ feel that**?

Which of these two expression is idiomatic here? or Do they both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the phrases you ask can work, but it's more natural to use "Why do you **feel like that**?"
You could use "Why do you **feel that way**?"